# jQuery CSS selector doesn't work on sap.m.table cell but addStyleClass does, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, sapui5

I have a table and I want to set the color of the cell in row 0 column 0 to red. However, the only programmatic way I am able to do this is through addStyleClass, which I do not want.

Here are a few things i've tried:

```
 oTable.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].$().css("background-color", "red");
```

&

```
 $(oTable.getItems()[0].getCells()[0]).css("background-color", "red")
```

&

```
$("#" + oTable.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].css("background-color", "red"))
```

However, none of these work. They don't give me any errors in the console though.

The only thing that works for me is:

```
oTable.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].addStyleClass("redBackground")
```

and setting background-color inside redBackground as red. I do not want to do that though because I will be setting the colors dynamically through data that my application will be getting.

Updated with JSfiddle: https://jsbin.com/sejavuqopa/2/edit?html,css,js,output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really liked the idea behind @alexP's answer, but I am neither a fan of jQuery (deprecated and will eventually be removed from UI5) nor of putting messages in the browser queue with `setTimeout` and a delay of zero.

So here is my approach:

```
oTable.placeAt("content");
// put new code directly behind placeAt
oTable.addEventDelegate({
   onAfterRendering: function () {
       oTable.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].getDomRef().parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
}, this);
```

Comment: Think this is the better way. I think the best way would be to use an event in bindItems? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Use a timeout. Also you have to use `.parent()` for coloring the whole cell instead of the number in that cell. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  oTable.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].$().parent().css("background-color", "red");
});
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yapunolotu/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if I should just create a new question for this but would you be able to explain why setTimeout fixes this issue? Asking because i'm now trying to place the setTimeout inside a double for loop that itererates through the rows and columns and it's not working & i'm trying to think of a way around it.

Comment: DOM (table cells) isn't ready for manipulation before timeout.